# Synchronise document library among two different sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have 2 Sharepoint Sites, Site A only accessible by internal colleagues due to security concern, Site B can be accessed by external party.

I wish to synchronise Site A document library with Site B document library. Whenever there is update (addition/deletion/modification for PDF, jpeg, MS Word/Excel) of file within Site A document library, Site B document library will do the same automatically.

Hope masters here can share the experience or advise on feasibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

> "Two-way sync", as its name suggests, is able to copy files in both
> directions, keeping the two SharePoint Documents libraries in sync and
> totally same with each other.
>
> Besides, it provides the "Real Time Sync", which will execute
> automatic sync as long as any changes are detected in the source cloud
> if you choose "One-way Sync" at the same time. If you choose "Real
> Time Sync"+"Two-way Sync". then the two SharePoint folders in two
> accounts will be synced in time as long as either has any
> modification. Also, 7 different sync methods are available for
> different requirements.

[https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/synchronize-two-sharepoint-document-libraries-7201.html#:~:text=Files%20On%20Demand-,Step%201.,%22Sync%22%20in%20the%20toolbar](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/synchronize-two-sharepoint-document-libraries-7201.html#:%7E:text=Files%20On%20Demand-,Step%201.,%22Sync%22%20in%20the%20toolbar).

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. Due to IT policy, is there any synchronization just remained within SharePoint and Power Automate, or Microsoft/Window? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, unfortunately, there seems to be no ootb way to achieve it.